# Creating searchable table/array in SQL from excel column

Tags: sql, excel

I have some programming experience but am brand new to SQL.

Basically I have about 300 terms that I want to search for in a single search.

What is the best way to store those terms in a way that I can iterate through them in a query? They're currently in an excel column and I'd prefer not to have to manually write each one in

Comment: I'd probably write a loop or store them in a dictionary and loop that. Your 'question' is open ended as to purpose

Comment: You could export them to a csv file and then import that into a database table via some admin tool… Depends on the database implementation you want to use.

Comment: I have an excel column that contains about 300 search terms that I want to search a separate database for. Each cell in the excel column is a word I want to search the database for.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * INTO EXCEL_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Excel\Spreadsheet.xls; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');
```

Will create a temporary table that you can run  your queries against.

```
   SELECT * FROM
   SEARCHABLEDATABASE
   WHERE column_of interest IN
   ( SELECT search_terms FROM EXCEL_IMPORT )
```

Or use the SQL Server import wizard

OR Simply run the select queries directly against the sheet.

EDIT: These two queries will match entries in a column of database to terms from a excel spreadsheet, providing they are exactly the same) you could TRIM them both to prevent differences in whitespace causing issue.

Comment: I maybe should have specified that I'm searching through a separate database, and am only using the excel column as a series of search terms. will this work in that respect?

Comment: See my update. I think thats what you need. Let me know if not.